# Can I redo with while block exception handling

Tags: perl, exception, while-loop

My exception handling catches the exception but redo throws some error.

I am using 3rd party api to get more than 5 million datas but that api frequently throws 500 error.

I am using exception handling and if any error occurs i want to redo the loop

```
eval{
while(my $productsRef = $se->iterate_products()) {
print Dumper($productsRef);
}
};
if ($@){
    sleep 30;
    redo;
}
```

The above code throws error if some exception is caught

```
cant "redo" outside the loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `redo` outside of loop or a [basic-block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Basic-BLOCKs),

```
REDO_EVAL: {
  my $ok = eval {
    while(my $productsRef = $se->iterate_products()) {
      print Dumper($productsRef);
    }
    1;
  };
  if (!$ok){
    # print "$@\n";
    sleep 30;
    redo;
  }
}
```